# Thymeleaf parsing error when using "&&" in AngularJS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, xml-parsing, thymeleaf

I have an AngularJS `ng-show` attribute  in my Thymeleaf template that looks something like this:

```
<span ng-show="aIsValid && bIsValid"></span>
```

When Thymeleaf tries to process this template, I get the following exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Does Thymeleaf just not play nicely with `&&` logic in Angular attributes? Or is there a workaround for this other than slapping a method on my `$scope` that will simply `return $scope.aIsValid && $scope.bIsValid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` because `&` must be escaped in XML.

Comment: That works - pretty gross to look at in the IDE though.

Comment: I ended up just refactoring the logic using `ng-hide` and `||` so that I don't have to use `&amp;&amp;` in my expression on the page, because it would be rather confusing to another developer who didn't know the context.